# Validation Rule for non admin profile

Tags: community

This is the validation rule that I have to implement can you please help me with it?

Add a validation rule – if profile is not sysadmin, value of status field must be New or Requested

Answer (score 2):

Are you a developer or Admin - i would assume not so here goes....

```
AND(
 NOT(
  OR(
   ISPICKVAL(STAGENAME, 'New'),ISPICKVAL(STAGENAME, 'Requested')
  )),
   $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator'
)
```